# return value when complete status appeared 2 times and above

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ori Data = #B

```
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
| RowNum | SeqNo |     Name      |  NameReason   |   NameDate    | Date-Of-Birth |  Status  |
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
|      1 | AAA   | ABC           | A             | 2019-01-01    | 1905-01-01    | Complete |
|      2 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Pending  |
|      3 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Pending  |
|      4 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Pending  |
|      5 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Complete |
|        |       |               |               |               |               |          |
|      1 | BBB   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1970-01-01    | Pending  |
|      2 | BBB   | DEF           | A             | 2019-01-02    | 1970-01-01    | Complete |
|      3 | BBB   | GHI           | A             | 2019-01-03    | 1970-01-01    | Complete |
|      4 | BBB   | ABC           | A             | 2019-01-03    | 1970-01-01    | Complete |
|      5 | BBB   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1970-01-01    | Pending  |
|        |       |               |               |               |               |          |
|      1 | CCC   | ABC           | A             | 2019-01-01    | 1990-01-01    | Complete |
|      2 | CCC   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1990-01-01    | Pending  |
|      3 | CCC   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1990-01-01    | Pending  |
|        |       |               |               |               |               |          |
|      1 | DDD   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 2001-05-02    | Pending  |
|      2 | DDD   | ABC           | A             | 2019-01-01    | 2001-05-02    | Complete |
|      3 | DDD   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 2001-05-02    | Pending  |
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

Desired Result:

```
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
| RowNum | SeqNo |     Name      |  NameReason   |   NameDate    | Date-Of-Birth |  Status  |
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
|      1 | AAA   | ABC           | A             | 2019-01-01    | 1905-01-01    | Complete |
|      2 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Pending  |
|      3 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Pending  |
|      4 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Pending  |
|      5 | AAA   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1905-01-01    | Complete |
|        |       |               |               |               |               |          |
|      1 | BBB   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1970-01-01    | Pending  |
|      2 | BBB   | DEF           | A             | 2019-01-02    | 1970-01-01    | Complete |
|      3 | BBB   | GHI           | A             | 2019-01-03    | 1970-01-01    | Complete |
|      4 | BBB   | ABC           | A             | 2019-01-03    | 1970-01-01    | Complete |
|      5 | BBB   | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 1970-01-01    | Pending  |
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

RowNum is row_num function that being filter correctly. I use rownum to partition seqno,date-of-birth order by date. This data is derived from Table #A and i insert it to #B.

Question:
Doesn't care how many row num i have, as long the **status='Completed' appeared 2 times and above, i want this data.** If status='Completed' appeared 1 time, just dont want the data.

Reason why my desired result like make no sense because I want to find out any changes in between and i will display it out if got changes (which i deal in another script)

Comment: use group by with having clause.

Comment: You are going to have to explain this. Your output makes no sense at all. Why are some rows returned and others not? Also you seem to be concerned about the order of rows but there is nothing in your data you can use to sort these. You also seem to be mixing datatypes. Things like dates and strings in a single column.

Comment: Is there any column be able to represent order of rows?

Comment: You have edited this but it still doesn't make much sense. You want all rows for a given SeqNo if there are at least rows with a status of "Complete"? Using a where exists would make short work of this.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this you want something along these lines.

```
declare @Something table
(
    RowNum int
    , SeqNo char(3)
    , Name varchar(20)
    , NameReason varchar(20)
    , NameDate varchar(20)
    , DateOfBirth date
    , Status varchar(20)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'AAA', 'ABC        ', 'A          ', '2019-01-01 ', '1905-01-01', 'Complete')
, (2, 'AAA', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1905-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (3, 'AAA', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1905-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (4, 'AAA', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1905-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (5, 'AAA', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1905-01-01', 'Complete')
, (1, 'BBB', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1970-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (2, 'BBB', 'DEF        ', 'A          ', '2019-01-02 ', '1970-01-01', 'Complete')
, (3, 'BBB', 'GHI        ', 'A          ', '2019-01-03 ', '1970-01-01', 'Complete')
, (4, 'BBB', 'ABC        ', 'A          ', '2019-01-03 ', '1970-01-01', 'Complete')
, (5, 'BBB', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1970-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (1, 'CCC', 'ABC        ', 'A          ', '2019-01-01 ', '1990-01-01', 'Complete')
, (2, 'CCC', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1990-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (3, 'CCC', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '1990-01-01', 'Pending ')
, (1, 'DDD', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '2001-05-02', 'Pending ')
, (2, 'DDD', 'ABC        ', 'A          ', '2019-01-01 ', '2001-05-02', 'Complete')
, (3, 'DDD', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', 'emptystring', '2001-05-02', 'Pending ')

select *
from @Something s
where exists 
(
    select s2.SeqNo
    from @Something s2
    where s2.SeqNo = s.SeqNo
        and s2.Status = 'Complete'
    group by s2.SeqNo
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want all lines for a given SeqNo that have more than 1 'Completed' status :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  B
WHERE
  SeqNo IN (
    SELECT
      SeqNo
    FROM
      B
    WHERE
      Status='Completed'
    GROUP BY
      SeqNo
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 1);
```

That's Oracle syntax. I hope you do have an index on SeqNo field.

Comment: instead of "where SeqNo in" you should indeed use "exists" which will probably results into better performance